# Need Help Refreshing my database ListView in my app

Tags: java, android, listview, auto-update

My app layout apparently isn't a normal layout so I a having trouble setting my List Adapter to auto updated when an edit is made.

I make my edits to my database in this Java File which is controlled in its own activity and layout.

```
    public void onClick(View view){
    if (view == findViewById(R.id.addsave)) {
        RecipeRepo repo = new RecipeRepo(this);
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
        if (editTextName.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            editTextName.setError("Recipe name required!");
            return;
        } else {
            recipe.name = editTextName.getText().toString();
        }
        if (textImagePath.getText().toString().equals("") ) {
            recipe.image = ("");
        }else{
            recipe.image = textImagePath.getText().toString();
        }
        recipe.category = staticSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (editTextIngredients.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            editTextIngredients.setError("Ingredient required!");
            return;
        } else {
            recipe.ingredients = editTextIngredients.getText().toString();
        }
        if (editTextInstruct.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            editTextIngredients.setError("Instruction required!");
            return;
        } else {
            recipe.instructions = editTextInstruct.getText().toString();
        }
        recipe.cooktemp = editTextCookTemp.getText().toString();
        recipe.cooktime = editTextCookTime.getText().toString();
        recipe.serves = editTextServings.getText().toString();
        recipe.recipe_Id = _Recipe_Id;

        if (_Recipe_Id == 0) {
            _Recipe_Id = repo.insert(recipe);

            Toast.makeText(this, "New Recipe Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
```

it actually inserts and updates in this java file

```
    int insert(Recipe recipe){

    //Open connection to write data
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_SERVES, recipe.serves);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_COOKTIME, recipe.cooktime);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_COOKTEMP, recipe.cooktemp);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_INSTRUCT, recipe.instructions);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_INGREDIENTS, recipe.ingredients);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_CATEGORY, recipe.category);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_IMAGE, recipe.image);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_NAME, recipe.name);

    //Inserting Row
    long recipe_Id = db.insert(Recipe.TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();// Closing database connection
    return (int) recipe_Id;
}

void delete(int recipe_Id){

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(Recipe.TABLE, Recipe.KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(recipe_Id)});
    db.close();
}

void update(Recipe recipe){

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Recipe.KEY_SERVES, recipe.serves);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_COOKTIME, recipe.cooktime);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_COOKTEMP, recipe.cooktemp);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_INSTRUCT, recipe.instructions);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_INGREDIENTS, recipe.ingredients);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_CATEGORY, recipe.category);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_IMAGE, recipe.image);
    values.put(Recipe.KEY_NAME, recipe.name);

    db.update(Recipe.TABLE, values, Recipe.KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(recipe.recipe_Id)});
    db.close();
}
```

and lastly it gets put into the list view from this Java file and separate layout.  Which is where my adapters are but i cannot get the notifyDataSetChanged() to work here at all... as in it wont even come up.

```
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    RecipeRepo repo = new RecipeRepo(this);

    if (id == R.id.nav_meat) {

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> recipeList = repo.getRecipeMeat();


        if(recipeList.size()!=0) {
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    recipe_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_Id);
                    String recipeId = recipe_Id.getText().toString();
                    Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecipeDetail.class);
                    objIndent.putExtra("recipe_Id", Integer.parseInt(recipeId));
                    startActivity(objIndent);
                }
            });
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SousChef.this, recipeList, R.layout.view_recipe_entry, new String[]{"id", "category", "name"}, new int[]{R.id.recipe_Id, R.id.recipe_list_category, R.id.recipe_list_name});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No recipe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_veg) {

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> recipeList = repo.getRecipeVeg();
        if(recipeList.size()!=0) {
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    recipe_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_Id);
                    String recipeId = recipe_Id.getText().toString();
                    Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecipeDetail.class);
                    objIndent.putExtra("recipe_Id", Integer.parseInt(recipeId));
                    startActivity(objIndent);
                }
            });
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SousChef.this, recipeList, R.layout.view_recipe_entry, new String[]{"id", "category", "name"}, new int[]{R.id.recipe_Id, R.id.recipe_list_category, R.id.recipe_list_name});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No recipe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

So any advise on setting this up to automatically update would be a huge help. I have been racking my brain over this for a couple days now looking at different examples and what not, but no setup is quite like this one which doesnt allow me to have everything in one file.

And thank you in advance.

category picking image:
[Category picking Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiXsm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are for sure more answers but this is one that might help,

**[Quick Example for the proposed solution](https://github.com/ArtiomLK/refreshListViewFromDBAndroid)**

**SHORT EXPLANATION**

inside `MainActivity`

```
//create a public static adapter
public static ListAdapter adapter
```

inside `onCreateView()`

```
//Create your adapter and set it to the right ListView
ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.listView_in_xml);
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(...)
lv.setAdapter(adapter)
```

inside `CustomAdapter` which in your case I assume is `SimpleAdapter`

```
//add a public method to be called so that the Adapter updates and displays the new data
public void updateMethod(){
   //update your List<Recipe> that I would guess you have calling the database again 
   //if needed update your getCount() return value so that it returns the number of childs in your ListView which most of the cases is just the List<Recipe>.size()
   //notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

inside your `DB HANDLER CLASS`

```
//in every update, add, delete or any method that requires the ListView to Update just call the created method,
MainActivity.CustomAdapter.updateMethod();
```

**PROBLEMS**

You will have to make sure the `public static adapter` has been initialized and is not null, or simply check whether the `adapter` is not `null` and update, because if the adapter is `null` that activity has not launched yet thus no need to trigger the `updateMethod()`.

**OTHER SOLUTIONS**

Instead of creating a `public static adapter` create a `public static boolean`, then whenever data changes set that boolean to true from the database.
Finally, whenever you resume your activity check against that boolean and update your ListViewAdapter if needed.

**MORE COMPLICATED SOLUTIONS WHICH I KNOW WORK CAUSE I USE IT**

Use `TaskAsyncTaskLoader` which utilizes a `Loader` in your `MainActivity` and implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`.

Optionally, you can make the `Loader` be, `public static Loader`and inside your `DBHandler` you trigger the loader to load the data again or use any other logic you want.

**Proofs of Working suggested solution,** 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll be giving it a try shortly sorry for the late response, I've been a bit busy.

Comment: The main problem I'm seeing with this, is that my SimpleAdapter is called multiple times, it is setup for a sliding navigation bar on the left side of the screen.  So it is for meats category, pasta category, drink category, etc...  is my update method going to end up being just as long, then with a bunch of if checks checking the category of what item was updated?

Comment: @Koumintang Are you saying that you are not truly updating values in the DB, but rather selecting a category and then the ListView should display the Items of that category which are in the DB?

Comment: no I'm updating the database, but when I pull up my list view, they are selected by the category column, my list view doesn't pull up every item in the database at once, unless i select it to pull them  all up at once. See image in edited question.

Comment: So each I have a category column in my database so that I can divide up the recipes and a person doesn't have to go through them all to find what they are looking for. Thus i with a click of meats it pulls only the recipes with the  MEATS category. and lets say your want to delete the recipe your on.  To do that you are in the recipe detail window which tells you the actual recipe details. click delete... detail activity closes, but it is still listed on the meats listview until you reload it manually(by clicking the meats nav_bar item again.

Comment: so my code to pull up my list view is setup like so

        if(id = R.id.nav_meats){
          pull up data base,
          find meat category
          setup adapter
          display inListview
         }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_pasta){
          pull up data base,
          find pasta category
          setup adapter
          display inListview
        }

Etc for each of the categorys.

Comment: @Koumintang I would suggest, do not create new `Adapters` every single time you select a category, but instead as I posted in the answer, create a single `public static SimpleAdapter` and force it to update when you delete a recipe or select a new category. I your scenario, when you open a new activity with your meat recipe and delete such meat recipe, going back to your previous activity still shows the meat recipe because you have not updated your `SimpleAdaper` values.

Comment: @Koumintang another method would be starting that second activity for Result, `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` then again when sent back to your first activity, update your Adapter-values. There are many tutorials on how to do this which is why I am not adding examples on this line.

Comment: bare with me, I'm trying to see how i can get away from calling the adapter for each click and only do it once... nothing I am doing seems to be with me...  The method you showed me makes sense... I'm just trying to get it to the point where i can use it.

Comment: ok so i managed to get it so that i only call my adapter once... Guess i needed to recharge myself to think clearly.  I'll be trying to implement your answer now.

Comment: Question, should i have the updateMethod pull .Extra data of the category field from insert, delete, and update methods so it updates the correct category?

Comment: @Koumintang Updated my answer, was working on an example which should help make this clearer in terms of the suggested solution, check the GitHub repository in the above [link](https://github.com/ArtiomLK/refreshListViewFromDBAndroid). As of your question, you would pass fresh updated data to the adapter from wherever you want, in the provided example I pass the data from the DB.

Comment: My biggest problem i was noticing with my code is that i'm not using a custom adapter to display my work, I am using only the arraylist and the listadapter, and apparently notifyDataSetChanged doesnt work with the list adapter itself.  I see how yours was supposed to work but I've just done a work around at the moment.  As i get a little more familar with the other adapters I can always update the app to do as i want it to do.

Comment: @Koumintang glad I could help and you could find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can Broadcast Intent from the change database file after you get the response in the onCreate() of adapter loading class

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("key_to_identify_the_broadcast");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("edttext", "changed");
    intent.putExtra("bundle_key_for_intent", bundle);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and then you can receive the bundle in your fragment by using the BroadcastReceiver class

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new 
BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = 
            intent.getExtras().getBundle("bundle_key_for_intent");
            if(bundle!=null){
                String edttext = bundle.getString("edttext");
            }
            //you can call any of your methods for using this bundle for your use case
    }
};
```

in onCreate() of your adapter adding class you need to register the broadcast receiver first otherwise this broadcast receiver will not be triggered

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("key_to_identify_the_broadcast");
getActivity().getApplicationContext().
               registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, filter);
```

Finally you can unregister the receiver to avoid any exceptions

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {

         getActivity().getApplicationContext().
             unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply i'll be giving it a try shortly.  Sorry for the late response I've just been busy.